# Execute test with vstest.console and parameters

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, mstest, data-driven-tests

I'm executing my test-dlls using the **vstest.console.exe** (the future mstest.exe) as a process in my application. I want to know if there's any possibility to **send parameters or datasource from my application to the testmethod.**

I've been searching for something like:

```
vstest.console.exe /Tests:DoSomething parameters.xml
```

or

```
vstest.console.exe /Tests:DoSomething /params:3,2,1
```

It would be even better if I could send these parameters **to the constructor** of the test class.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't seen any commands that make this happen. 
Official command line documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/jj155796.aspx

You could author your tests to load from an external file (xml, ini, etc.) or source (db) which would simulate this. If the application were to generate the data, the test methods could load it and use the data during execution.

I've been doing something similar where I generate a setting file containing various information for a web application to be tested, it then launches the test and the tests load from that data file and use the settings for parameters.

Comment: You're right. I've chosen the communication over a XML file. I tried to use the Settingsfile at first, too, but the problem was that I can't manipulate it from outside when the test file has been built, because the settings file isn't a separated one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the parameter `/Settings:` to load parameters from a XML config file (*.runsettings).

In this answer you see a good example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56846722/789423